# struggling to implement simple boost::graph traversal

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

I'm struggling to implement a simple boost::graph.  I've tried to read all the documentation I can find and examples etc...

Here is my code (copied from other examples on StackOverflow)

The vertex:

```
class customvertex
{
public:
    double some_member;
};
```

The Visitor:

```
class MyVisitor : public boost::default_dfs_visitor
{
public:
    void discover_vertex(MyGraphVertex v, const MyGraph& g) const
    {
        std::cout << v << std::endl;
        return;
    }
};
```

The typedef declaration:

```
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS,boost::vecS,boost::undirectedS, customvertex> MyGraph;
typedef boost::graph_traits<MyGraph>::vertex_descriptor MyGraphVertex;
```

The code that causes a problem:

```
MyGraph theGraph;
customvertex a;
MyGraphVertex vert_a = boost::add_vertex(a, theGraph);

customvertex b;
MyGraphVertex vert_b = boost::add_vertex(b, theGraph);

boost::add_edge(vert_a , vert_b, theGraph);

MyVisitor vis;
boost::depth_first_search(theGraph, boost::visitor(MyVisitor()));
```

The final call to depth_first_search causes the compiler to throw out a 112 line cascading error.
The concepts seem to be IncidenceGraphConcept and MultiPassInputIterator

The key parts seem to be:

```
1>        T:\boost\boost_1_47_0\boost/concept/detail/msvc.hpp(23) : while compiling class template member function 'void boost::concepts::check<Model>::failed(Model *)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            Model=boost::SignedInteger<int>
1>        ]

1>        T:\boost\boost_1_47_0\boost/graph/depth_first_search.hpp(83) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::function_requires<boost::concepts::IncidenceGraphConcept<G>>(Model *)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            G=MyGraph,
1>            Model=boost::concepts::IncidenceGraphConcept<MyGraph>
1>        ]
1>        T:\boost\boost_1_47_0\boost/graph/depth_first_search.hpp(202) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::detail::depth_first_visit_impl<VertexListGraph,DFSVisitor,ColorMap,boost::detail::nontruth2>(const IncidenceGraph &,unsigned int,DFSVisitor &,ColorMap,TerminatorFunc)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            VertexListGraph=MyGraph,
1>            DFSVisitor=const MyVisitor,
1>            ColorMap=boost::shared_array_property_map<boost::default_color_type,boost::vec_adj_list_vertex_id_map<boost::property<boost::vertex_bundle_t,customvertex>,unsigned int>>,
1>            IncidenceGraph=MyGraph,
1>            TerminatorFunc=boost::detail::nontruth2
1>        ]
```

Any and all help most appreciated.
I'm sure I'm missing something simple and I can usually figure it out from examples.  I think boost::graph looks great, perfect for what I need, but a bit more documentation......

I'm reasonably experienced with template programming but I've spent too many hours on this now, time to ask for help!

Comment: don't you want `boost::visitor(vis)` ?

Comment: According to the documentation, [`depth_first_search`](http://www.boost.org/libs/graph/doc/depth_first_search.html) only works with directed graphs, but using boost 1.54 on g++ 4.8.1 an example using the fragments you posted seems to work. There is another algorithm that should work when your graph is undirected: [`undirected_dfs`](http://www.boost.org/libs/graph/doc/undirected_dfs.html). So maybe you should try to see if that works in your Visual Studio version.

Comment: @Guy Sirton: yes I do, that's just a fragment from me messing around with the code a lot

Comment: @cv_and_he: yeah, I thought that so I tried many combinations of directed and undirected graphs and searches.  Above is pretty much lifted from another example.  So that fragment above works for you?  hmm....

Comment: @KenMoynihan Can you try to build us a smaller self contained sample showing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

From [this GitHub](https://github.com/richelbilderbeek/boost_graph_example_5) I have copied a similar working (and tested) example:

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/visitors.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/depth_first_search.hpp>

struct Node
{
  Node(const int t = 0) : m_t{t} {}
  int m_t;
};

/// A phylogeny is a graph of Node of different generations
/// connected by ancestry
using phylogeny = boost::adjacency_list<
  boost::vecS,
  boost::vecS,
  boost::undirectedS,
  Node
>;

using phylogeny_vd = boost::graph_traits<phylogeny>::vertex_descriptor;

class my_visitor : public boost::default_dfs_visitor
{
public:
  void discover_vertex(phylogeny_vd vd, const phylogeny& g) const
  {
    std::cout << g[vd].m_t << std::endl;
  }
};

//Create a phylogeny
//
//        b---c---d
//        |
//    a---+
//        |
//        e---f---g
//
// ---+---+---+---+---
//    0   1   2   3  t (generation)
phylogeny create_phylogeny()
{
  phylogeny p;
  const auto a = boost::add_vertex(Node(0), p);
  const auto b = boost::add_vertex(Node(1), p);
  const auto c = boost::add_vertex(Node(2), p);
  const auto d = boost::add_vertex(Node(3), p);
  const auto e = boost::add_vertex(Node(1), p);
  const auto f = boost::add_vertex(Node(2), p);
  const auto g = boost::add_vertex(Node(3), p);
  boost::add_edge(a, b, p);
  boost::add_edge(b, c, p);
  boost::add_edge(c, d, p);
  boost::add_edge(a, e, p);
  boost::add_edge(f, g, p);
  return p;
}

int main()
{
  const phylogeny p = create_phylogeny();
  my_visitor v;
  boost::depth_first_search(
    p,
    boost::visitor(v)
  );
}
```